# Complex Measures: Integration

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, measure-theory, banach-spaces

**Reference**

A rigorous treatment can be found in: [Complex Measures: Integrability](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/970270/79762)

**Problem**

Integration w.r.t. complex measure usually is defined via the Radon-Nikodym derivative:
$$\int f\mathrm{d}\mu:=\int fu\mathrm{d}|\mu|\quad(\mathrm{d}\mu=u\mathrm{d}|\mu|)$$
Alternatively one could define:
$$\int f\mathrm{d}\mu:=\sum_{\alpha=0\ldots3}i^\alpha\int f\mathrm{d}\mu_\alpha$$
with the decomposition:
$$\mu=\Re_+\mu-\Re_-\mu+i\Im_+\mu-i\Im_-\mu=:\sum_{\alpha=0\ldots3}i^\alpha\mu_\alpha$$

How to check that these definitions agree formally?

**Disclaimer**

This thread is meant as summary. For more informations see:

- [SE blog: Answer own Question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)
- [MSE meta: Answer own Question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/4680/79762)

*(The second especially reveals the opinion of the community!)*

Comment: I'm looking for textbooks about integration w.r.t. signed measures. Could you share the textbook you are using?

Comment: The better way is to use instead the operator algebraic approach, that is take the algebra of continuous functions $C(X,\mathbb{C})$ and then to simply consider the bounded linear functionals $\phi:C(X,\mathbb{C})\to\mathbb{C}$ as a replacement for integration against a complex measure. You may then always decompose your complex measure (meaning the bounded linear functional) via the Hahn decomposition into a sum of four positive linear functionals $\phi = (\operatorname{Re}\phi)_+-(\operatorname{Re}\phi)_- + i(\operatorname{Im}\phi)_+ - i(\operatorname{Im}\phi)_-$. ...

Comment: You may then still think of these bounded linear functionals as (integration against) complex measures, but also basically forget about "points in space" which are **E-N-T-I-R-E-L-Y IRRELEVANT** in the context of measure theory anyways!

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! Again, may I ask for the textbook you use?

Comment: Hi again Akira, unfortunately I don't really have a textbook for the statement and approach in mind right now from the top of my head. It is more of another viewpoint coming from operator algebras, so one could maybe look for some references in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formally it holds:
$$\int fu\mathrm{d}|\mu|=\sum_{\alpha}i^\alpha\int f_\alpha u\mathrm{d}|\mu|=\sum_{\alpha,\beta}i^{\alpha+\beta}\int f_\alpha u_\beta \mathrm{d}|\mu|=\sum_{\beta}i^\beta\int f\mathrm{d}\mu_\beta$$