# Complex Measures: Integrability

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, measure-theory, definition

**Problem**

On the one hand, a complex measure decomposes into:
$$\mu=\Re_+\mu-\Re_-\mu+i\Im_+\mu-i\Im_-\mu=:\sum_{\alpha=0\ldots3}i^\alpha\mu_\alpha$$

This gives rise to the integrability condition:
$$f\in L(\mu)\iff f\in L(\mu_\alpha)\quad(\alpha=1,\ldots,3)$$

On the other hand, a complex measure admits a derivative:
$$\mu(E)=\int_Eu\mathrm{d}|\mu|\quad(|u|=1)$$

This gives rise to the integrability condition:
$$f\in L(\mu):\iff fu\in L(|\mu|)\iff f\in L(|\mu|)$$

> So the question arises wether these approaches coincide:
>   $$f\in L(|\mu|)\iff f\in L(\mu_\alpha)\quad(\alpha=1,\ldots,3)$$

**Attempt**

So far by construction it is:
$$\mu_\alpha(E)=\int_Eu_\alpha\mathrm{d}|\mu|\quad(0\leq u_\alpha\leq1)$$
which gives for positive functions:
$$\int|f|\mathrm{d}\mu_\alpha=\int|f|u_\alpha\mathrm{d}|\mu|\leq\int |f|\mathrm{d}|\mu|$$
That proves the inclusion:
$$f\in L(|\mu|)\implies f\in L(\mu_\alpha)\quad(\alpha=1,\ldots,3)$$
But what about the converse?

**Related**

For a formal treatment see: [Complex Measures: Integration](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/950599/79762)

For a related recapitulation see: [Complex Measures: Variation](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/950627/79762)

For a similar problem see: [Complex Functions: Integrability](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/970046/79762)

For a general problem see: [Radon-Nikodym: Integrability?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/970004/79762)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In fact, the very very heart of the whole story here are the two inequalities:
>   $$|\mu(E)|\leq|\mu|(E)<\infty\quad(E\in\Sigma)$$

For positive measures given as derivative:
$$\kappa(E)=\int_Eh\mathrm{d}\lambda\quad(h\geq0)$$
the positive integrals agree:
$$\int f\mathrm{d}\kappa=\int fh\mathrm{d}\lambda\quad(f\geq0)$$
*(Note, these are allowed to be infinite!)*

Now, consider the representation by the Radon-Nikodym derivative:
$$\mu_\alpha=\int_Eu_\alpha\mathrm{d}|\mu|\quad(u_\alpha\geq0,|u|=1)$$
Exploiting the bounds:
$$u_\alpha\leq|u|$$
$$|u|\leq\sum_{\alpha=0\ldots3}u_\alpha$$
one has the estimates:
$$\int|f|\mathrm{d}\mu_\alpha=\int|f|\cdot u_\alpha\mathrm{d}|\mu|\leq\int|f|\cdot|u|\mathrm{d}|\mu|=\int|f|\mathrm{d}|\mu|$$
$$\int|f|\mathrm{d}|\mu|=\int|f|\cdot|u|\mathrm{d}|\mu|\leq\sum_{\alpha=0\ldots3}\int|f|\cdot u_\alpha\mathrm{d}|\mu|=\sum_{\alpha=0\ldots3}\int|f|\mathrm{d}\mu_\alpha$$
and therefore:
$$f\in L(|\mu|)\iff f\in L(\mu_\alpha)\quad(\alpha=0\ldots3)$$

Comment: Don't forget that Radon-Nikodym requires $\sigma$-finite. There are restrictions on using Radon-Nikodym. And don't forget that $|\mu|$ is a finite measure for a complex measure $\mu$--that's useful in applying the theorem.

Comment: Can you tell me where exactly, please?

Comment: If you want to take derivatives with respect to $|\mu|$, then it is worth nothing that $|\mu|$ is finite (at least it should be $\sigma$-finite to apply RN.)

Comment: I'm sorry I really don't see where... Can you tell me which formula?

Comment: Where you write "Now, consider the representation by the Radon-Nikodym derivative..."

Comment: But the total variation is even finite $|\mu|(\Omega)<\infty$... Or am I missing something? Just to be sure: I'm taking the decomposition from the question above.

Comment: That's what I wrote: you should mention that total variation for any complex measure is finite. That's not an obvious fact. And $\mu_{\alpha}$ need to be so, too.

Comment: But even if it wouldn't be the case the whole prove would still work as long as one has a derivative $\mu(E)=\int_Ehd|\mu|$ with $|h|=1$ which is not restricted to sigma-finiteness of $|\mu|$. Wouldn't it?

Comment: It's later where you specifically invoke Radon-Nikodym, which requires $\sigma$-finite measures.

Comment: Do you mean since I'm postulating the existence of a Radon-Nikodym derivative?

Comment: If you've invoking the Radon-Nikodym Theorem, yes. If not, then something else needs to be said.

Comment: Oh ok but I guess that's fine since I stated it already as given in the 'very first line' in the question and in fact that would serve better for a new thread...

Comment: Or just point to what I wrote.

Comment: So you are hypothesizing the existence of $\mu_{\alpha}E=\int_{E}h_{\alpha}d|\mu|$?

Comment: Yepp! That is even the usual way to construct the RN derivative for complex measures by first proving the existence of the RN derivative for the positive negative real imaginary variations and then patching all together...

Comment: And you didn't invoke the Radon-Nikodym Theorem in doing that?

Comment: Yes but for the finite positive measures: $\mu_\alpha(E)\leq|\mu|(E)<\infty$

Comment: Okay, so it was critical to mention that $|\mu|$ was finite. Back to square one.

Comment: @T.A.E.: In fact, the inequality $|\mu(E)|\leq|\mu|(E)<\infty$ is the very very core of the whole story here!

Answer (score 3):

If we have a signed measure $\mu$ on a measurable space $(\Omega,\Sigma)$, then $\mu$ may be allowed to assume values of $\pm \infty$, but not both. A complex measure $\mu$ is not allowed to assume any type of infinite value. For either type of measure $\mu$ which is not allowed to assume infinite values, the variation measure $|\mu|$ is a finite measure, where
$$
             |\mu|E = \sup_{\pi}\sum_{S \in \pi}|\mu S|
$$
is taken over all finite partitions $\pi$ of measurable subsets of $E$. Because we want to deal with a complex measure, then we assume without loss of generality that all measures related to this discussion are finite.

If $\mu$ is a signed measure, then we can decompose $\mu$ into positive meausres $\mu_{+}$, $\mu_{-}$ according to the (Hahn) Jordan decomposition. This decomposition is the same as a variation measure approach:
$$
                    |\mu|=\mu_{+}+\mu_{-},\;\;\; \mu = \mu_{+}-\mu_{-}.
$$
This extends to the complex case as well
$$
                \mu = (\Re\mu)_{+}-(\Re\mu)_{-}+i\{(\Im\mu)_{+}-(\Im\mu)_{-}\}
$$
with
$$
            |\mu| \le |\Re\mu| + |\Im\mu| = |(\Re\mu)_{-}|+|(\Re\mu)_{+}|+|(\Im\mu)_{-}|+|(\Im\mu)_{+}|.
$$
But we also have
$$
                       |\Re\mu| \le |\mu|,\;\;\; |\Im\mu| \le |\mu|.
$$
So integrability of a function $f$ with respect to $|\mu|$ is equivalent to simultaneous integrability with respect to $|(\Re\mu)_{-}|,|(\Re\mu)_{+}|,|(\Im\mu)_{-}|,|(\Im\mu)_{+}|$.

Comment: Hope, you don't mind that I posted an answer as well... I'm glad for your answer anyway!! (+1)